# Is it always poor performance when using the entire table in DAX?

Tags: powerbi, dax

So I am reading that using the table name causes table expansion which results in slow performance.

I understand that this can happen when tablename is used in FILTER. However if I use the tablename in REMOVEFILTERS, then does this also cause table expansion/poor performance?

Answer (score 0):

No, when you use REMOVEFILTERS, DAX engine only marks the expanded table from which all the filters are to be removed and thats all it does, this doesn't have any performance impact.

Refering table names in basic calculations is fine the problem arises when you nest iterators and there are complex code in the row context and also if the cardinality of the each iterator is pretty high then in most of the cases what DAX engine would do is it would materialize the whole table in memory in form of a data cache on which the Formula Engine will later iterate.

Huge materialized tables are a big problem because the architecture of Vertipaq is to reduce the RAM usage, but the materialized tables are uncompressed tables in memory and they can consume a lot of RAM.

If you want to create materialization yourself for testing, then try using SAMPLE or GROUBPY as a top level function and use DAX Studio to confirm the materialization.

My advice is to always use a single column whenever you can, this allows for faster scanning of the columns/dictionary, more columns will require scanning of the columns and then joining them.